# Wild cluster bootstrap after linear model with multiple fixed effects

Tags: r, stata, standard-error

I am running a linear model with multiple fixed effects. I suspect that there is spatial correlation in my data so I cluster the SEs (46 clusters). But I am worried that the standard errors generated by `felm::lfe` (and `reghdfe` in Stata) might be too large. So I want to alternatively also compute wild cluster bootstrap (WCB) based confidence intervals for the main parameters.

This does not seem to be an easy thing to do for panel models with multiple fixed effects. Here's a summary of what I found:

- Stata: Current procedures to do WCB on stata (`boottest`, `clustse`,
  `cgmwildboot`) do not work with procedures that implement multiple
  fixed effects (`reghdfe`, `areg`). `reghdfe` itself does not [currently](https://github.com/sergiocorreia/reghdfe/issues/42)
  support WCB.
- R: The `felm` package that seems to be the best option
  for linear panel models with multiple FE and clustered SE does not support WCB. In fact,
  it does not even support `predict` after the regression.

So, there seem to be two possible solutions:

1. **Workaround**: WCB procedures on stata work with one level of FE (for example, `boottest`). So, converting the `reghdfe` regression to include dummies and absorbing the one FE with largest set would probably work with `boottest`. But this is likely to be crazily expensive on memory and processing capacity. If I have access to high-performance servers I could run this code on those servers.
2. **Code own WCB function in R**: The second option is to get predictions from `felm` regression (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491545/predict-method-for-felm-from-lfe-package?answertab=votes#tab-top) process from a previous answer on Stack Overflow). Then one could write a function to do the wild cluster bootstrap and get the confidence interval for estimated coefficients.

There are probably better solutions out there. What would the community suggest as best practice to get wild cluster bootstrap based CI after a panel regression with multiple fixed effects?

Comment: Hi Peter, 
Thanks for your response. I can see why this question might be a better fit on CrossValidated. But perhaps people might have tried to code up the wild cluster bootstrap after felm and run into difficulties? That would be useful to know.

I will ask this question on CrossValidated as well. Thanks!

Comment: As a sidenote: the fixest package comes with a predict method (contrary to lfe).

Answer (score 1):

The `fwildclusterboot` R package implements a wild cluster bootstrap and allows for multiple fixed effects. The package is a port of the `boottest` package in Stata.
`fwildclusterboot` accepts objects of type `felm` and `fixest` where multiple fixed effects are out-projected in the estimation stage. In the bootstrap inference stage, it converts all fixed effects to sets of dummy variables but allows the user to specify one fixed effect to be projected out in the bootstrap - just as in the `boottest.ado` Stata routine.

````
library(fwildclusterboot)
library(fixest)

# load data set voters included in fwildclusterboot
data(voters)

# estimate the regression model via feols
feols_fit <- feols(proposition_vote ~ treatment + ideology1 + log_income | Q1_immigration , data = voters)
# boottest on an object of type fixest, no fixed effect used for inference
boot_feols <- boottest(feols_fit, clustid = "group_id1", param = "treatment", B = 99999, tol = 1e-08)
# now, project out "Q1_immigration" during bootstrap
boot_feols_fe <- boottest(feols_fit, clustid = "group_id1", param = "treatment", B = 99999, fe = "Q1_immigration", tol = 1e-08)

library(modelsummary)
msummary(list(boot_feols, boot_feols_fe), 
         estimate = "{estimate} ({p.value})", 
         statistic = "[{conf.low}, {conf.high}]", 
         digits = 3, 
         output = "markdown")


#|          |    Model 1     |    Model 2     |
#|:---------|:--------------:|:--------------:|
#|treatment | 0.073 (0.001)  | 0.073 (0.001)  |
#|          | [0.033, 0.113] | [0.033, 0.113] |
#|Num.Obs.  |      300       |      300       |
#|R2        |     0.316      |     0.316      |
#|R2 Adj.   |     0.288      |     0.288      |
#|R2 Within |     0.052      |     0.052      |
#|R2 Pseudo |                |                |
#|AIC       |     -84.1      |     -84.1      |
#|BIC       |     -35.9      |     -35.9      |
#|Log.Lik.  |     55.025     |     55.025     |
```
````

Comment: Hi @A.Fischer, I did try boottest on stata directly as mentioned in the question. It's nice to have a port to it directly from R so fixest/felm work (and thanks for letting me know about its existence), but the issue with memory will likely come up, given that all other fixed effects are converted to dummies. Thanks, Anshuman

Comment: Hi, sorry, I think I read over your comment regarding memory. I believe that the main memory problem with many high-dimensional fixed effects in the algorithm as implemented in fwildclusterboot is due to the inversion of (X'X). With many high-dimensional fixed effects, X should probably be a sparse matrix (which it currently is not), and if that is not sufficiently helpful, solve(crossprod(X)) could also be implemented via the bigstatr package.

Comment: Hi, you're right about the fact that most of the high-dimensional fixed effects are zeros for most observations. I would try to do something but I found another estimation strategy that does not rely on linear regression so I don't quite have the incentive right now. But I think this issue will persist for many use cases. Thanks for your observations!